# How to use ValidationPipe to transform json to objcet from body while using FileInterceptor to upload file?

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs, pipe

I using the below code to do file upload.But seem the `@Body('body') createFileDto: CreateFileDto` can't be proccess by ValidationPipe and throw error: *an unknown value was passed to the validate function.*

```js
@Controller('files')
export class FilesController {
  constructor(private readonly filesService: FilesService) {}

  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  uploadFileToServer(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @Body('body') createFileDto: CreateFileDto,
    @ActiveUser() user: ActiveUserType,
  ) {
    console.log(createFileDto);
    return this.filesService.create(createFileDto, file, user);
  }
}
```

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    bufferLogs: true,
  });
  app.useLogger(app.select(LoggerModule).get(CustomLogger));
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      enableDebugMessages: true,
      // forbidUnknownValues: false,
    }),
  );
  app.listen(configService.get<number>('appPort'), () => {
    const logger = new Logger('Bootstrap');
    logger.log(
      `${configService.get<string>(
        'appName',
      )} service is running on port:${configService.get<number>('appPort')}`,
    );
  });
}
```

```js
export class CreateFileDto {
  fileName?: string;

  expirationTime?: number;
}
```

I expecting ValidationPipe can process json parese and the transform just like others. Now I try to use custom pipe to do with it.

```js
@Injectable()
export class JsonParsePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any) {
    try {
      const obj = JSON.parse(value);
      return obj;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new BadRequestException(err.message);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class TransformPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private logger: CustomLogger) {}
  transform(obj: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    let tarnsFormObj: any = undefined;
    if (this.isConstructor(metadata.metatype)) {
      tarnsFormObj = new metadata.metatype();
      for (const key in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
          tarnsFormObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
      }
    } else {
      this.logger.warn(`TransformPipe not transform the object`, TransformPipe.name, obj);
    }
    return tarnsFormObj ?? obj;
  }
  private isConstructor(f: any): f is Constructor {
    try {
      Reflect.construct(String, [], f);
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

```js
  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  uploadFileToServer(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @Body('body', JsonParsePipe, TransformPipe) _createFileDto: CreateFileDto,
    @ActiveUser() user: ActiveUserType,
  ) {
    return this.filesService.create(_createFileDto, file, user);
  }
```

Comment: You don't need to pass anything to `@Body()`. In your case, you only need to invoke it without passing any argument.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What version of class-validator and class-transformer do you use?